# Printers Sharing Ubuntu Server

Tags: windows, ubuntu, samba, printing

I need to share 3 USB printers on a network, I installed a Raspberry Pi4 with Ubuntu Server 20.04 LTS with CUPS e smb services configured. From windows 10 I'm able to access \ip of the server and I see all the printers. The issue is when I try to connect to the printer, Windows show me this error " No more connections can be made to the remote computer now because the maximum number of connections that the computer can accept has been exceeded ".  I have tried from a Windows 10 PC and a Windows Server 2016. How can I solve this error? Is there a maximum connection limit to set on Ubuntu server ?

thanks

Comment: it looks like for me as it would be a enduser question and this kind of requests are off-topic on serverfault.com. you may want to ask on superuser.com

Comment: The question is on-topic as it is dealing with networking services plausibly in a business environment.

Comment: Did you try to connect to CUPS via IPP protocol (not Samba)?

Comment: Yes through IPP printer was working, but I need to use samba sharing. I solved the problem providing the customer with a usb printer server. Thanks to all for the reply